# Consumer API card testing

Tags: credit-card, banno-digital-toolkit

I am attempting to call the /cards endpoint using the Garden sandbox account.  As of now, I cannot figure out how to add a credit/debit card to my sandbox and the endpoint is returning null for any card given the user account.

Am I missing a step?  The code looks right and I believe I have the correct scopes in place:

'https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/cardcontrols.readonly' : null,
'https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/cards' : null

I also cannot find any documentation to where I can get the full unmasked card details, but that's another issue.  I'd like to start by just being able to retrieve a configured card.

Thank you!

```
// Cards: /users/{userId}/cards
//
async function getCards(consumerApiPath, userId, accessToken) {
  const cardApiResponse = await fetch(`${consumerApiPath}${userId}/cards`, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken }
  });
  const cardApiJson = await cardApiResponse.json();
  const cards = cardApiJson.cards;
  return cards;
}

// returns NULL as I believe no card is configured in the Garden sandbox`
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to unravel, so please bear with me.

#### Scopes vs Claims (in general)

The [GET /users/{userId}/cards](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/cards/details/#/Basic%20Cards/get_users__userId__cards) endpoint requires the `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/cardcontrols.readonly` OAuth scope to be part of the *scope* parameter in the auth URL. That's how you'll get the necessary permissions in the *Access Token* for that endpoint.

- The [Authentication (Command Line)](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/quickstarts/authenticationcommandline/) quickstart is a good resource to learn about using scopes in the auth URL.

The `https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/cards` claim can be used in the *claims* parameter to get "debit and credit cards with full unmasked card numbers" in the *Identity Token*. Note that particular claim falls under the ["Restricted Claims"](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/openidconnectoauth/) which means that an admin at the financial institution would need to enable that claim before you would receive data in the *Identity Token*.

- The [Claims in the Identity Token](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/guides/claimsintheidentitytoken/) guide is a good resource to learn about using claims in the auth URL.

(Your sample gave me a clue that there may be some confusion on the difference between scopes and claims.)

#### Accessing the Digital Toolkit (in the *Garden* demo institution)

The [self-serve developer accounts on JackHenry.Dev](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/accessing-the-digital-toolkit/) offer, amongst other things, the creation of a test user in the *Garden* demo institution. That test user will have:

- Checking account
- Savings account

Notably, there aren't any *debit cards* nor *credit cards* created for the test user.

#### Configuration of Cards (at a financial institution)

For both banks and credit unions, retrieving debit card info via the API requires the institution to have the Basic Card Controls feature in Banno for the institution. For credit cards, I believe it requires having JHA Full Service Credit contracted and installed for Banno for the institution.

It's my understanding that some portion of this would require contracts to be in place to enable the feature in Banno, but that's not my area of expertise. I would suggest that the financial institution speak with their account representative for more info on getting this set up in Banno for their institution.